# Chinese FrSky radio receiver, what is this component?

Tags: identification, remote-control

I have one of these cheap chinese RC receivers mounted on a quadcopter. After one too many hard landings this component broke into pieces. I would like to try repairing the board by replacing it, but I have no idea what this component was, or what was it's value.

I have looked online for a schematic but as it is an unofficial chinese knock-off, I couldn't find any.

[image: FrSky receiver]

Comment: It's a crystal used as the clock for this ATMEGA328P chip. Usually it is an 8 MHz or 16 MHz crystal. Next time: identify the chip, download the datasheet of the chip, check which pins the component is connected to and look in the datasheet what those pins are for and what components are connected to it.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie that is actually an answer and should be put in the field below.

Answer (score 1):

This is a ceramic resonator which is used to generate a stable frequency for operation.

The problem is finding the correct frequency. The 'A' is likely the frequency code and the 'H' is probably the production date code. At least that way it is done by Murata. With a short search I wasn't able to find a comprehensive list of frequency codes to determine which frequency that is.

If it isn't a resonator from Murata, then you'd have to check other manufacturers but there aren't that many around. Most of them are just reselling stuff.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie is probably right in that it is either an 8 or 16MHz resonator, as these are commonly used with these atmegas.